# im sending request to java server using PHP Curl function but not recived any response from server our server not support file_get_contents() fuction

Tags: php, json, curl, response

im sending request to java server 
im using PHP Curl function 
static ip our server not support
im getting blank response from server im try all most Curl methods but not getting solutions.

```
    <?php

$headers = array(
               'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
);

$p1="9503680548";
$p2="MR";
$p3="MA";
$p4="KL";
$p5="10";
$p6="pom123";
$p7="pom123456";
$p8="123568";

$url="http://domain/rest/apiCallForTxn/recharge?";
$url.="serviceNo=".$p1."&serviceType=".$p2."&serviceSubType=".$p3."&circleCode=".$p4."&amount=".$p5."&userCode=".$p6."&password=".$p7."&clientTransactionId=".$p8;

$ch = curl_init();
// Set the url, number of GET vars, GET data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Execute request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

// get the result and parse to JSON
$obj = json_decode($result, true);

echo $obj['SERVICE_NO'];
echo "</br>";
echo $obj['AMOUNT'];
echo "</br>";
echo $obj['SERVICE_TYPE'];
echo "</br>";
echo $obj['TXN_ID'];
echo "</br>";
echo $obj['STATUS'];
?>
```

Comment: Call `$info = curl_getinfo($ch);` before `curl_close($ch);` and then `var_dump($info)`

Comment: var_dump what it function does...???? thanks for replay

Comment: its show array result but not actualy i want.....not work